# How do I validate IBOutlet/var for nil?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I've written a simple application using Swift and Xcode 6.1.1. The program, which is a simple calculator, works well but I haven't been able to validate non-nil input for the three text fields. As a result, if the user leaves the field blank and then hits "calculate," the application crashes.

The app takes three inputs, initially as strings. I wrote an if statement to check for nil but it doesn't work - it will just pass to else regardless. Here's the code block that's relevant to my question:

```
...
@IBOutlet var calcButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var yearOneField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var yearTwoField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var yearThreeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var displayWindow: UILabel!

@IBAction func calcButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (yearOneField == nil) {

        displayWindow.text = ("Non-zero entries are not permitted. Please enter new values.")

    } else {

    let yearOne = yearOneField.text.toInt()
    let yearTwo = yearTwoField.text.toInt()
    let yearThree = yearThreeField.text.toInt()
    ...
```

I was thinking I could evaluate the IBOutlet for nil but that didn't work. I'm new to Swift and Xcode so I hope this is a n00b question to the more experienced developers out there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text fields themselves will never be `nil`. They are created and assigned during initialization, and you're never removing them.

I think you want to check if their `text` properties contain any text, which you can do like this:

*Updated for Swift 2:*

```
if let text = yearOneField.text where !text.isEmpty {
    // perform the conversions
} else {
    // the text field is empty
}
```

You can avoid nesting using `guard`:

```
guard let text = yearOneField.text where !text.isEmpty else {
    // the text field is empty
    return
}

// perform the conversions
```

I prefer the `guard` syntax because it's clearer about what the *ideal* result is.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, that was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The only way the `@IBOutlet`s could be `nil` is if you forgot to wire them up in *Interface Builder*.  Usually you don't need to check that because the crash will tell you to fix that problem.

The `toInt()` function returns an Optional `Int` (aka `Int?`) that must be unwrapped before being used.  `toInt()` will return `nil` if the value in the text field does not represent a valid `Int`.  "2.1", "seven", and "" would all return `nil` if converted with `toInt()`.  I recommend you use optional binding (`if let`) syntax to check the conversion for `nil` and unwrap the result if it is not `nil`:

```
if let yearOne = yearOneField.text.toInt() {
    if let yearTwo = yearTwoField.text.toInt() {
        if let yearThree = yearThreeField.text.toInt() {
            // yearOne, yearTwo, and yearThree are all valid Ints
            // so do the calculations
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you know you want to use a default value (like `0`) when the field can't be converted to an `Int`, you can unwrap the result using the *nil coalescing operator* `??` like so:

```
let yearOne = yearOneField.text.toInt() ?? 0
let yearTwo = yearTwoField.text.toInt() ?? 0
let yearThree = yearThreeField.text.toInt() ?? 0
```

Comment: Thanks @vacawama. I'm going to try this out to try and make my code a bit smarter.

Comment: What if an async function returns after you've navigated away from a view? If you make a reference to an IBOutlet in the completion handler, will it be nil?

Comment: @FateNuller, either your closure captured `self` in which case the viewController will hang around until your closure is done and releases the strong pointer to `self`, or if you use `[weak self]` to have a weak pointer to the viewController, then when the viewController is deallocated, your `self` will be set to `nil` and you won't have access to the `@IBOutlets` because they will be long gone.  In either case, you don't have to worry about the outlets being `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check as you do with normal optionals.

```
 guard let unwrapped = myLabel else {return}
```

Or like this

```
 if myLabel == nil {
    //do stuff
 }
```

Or like this:

```
 if let unwrappedLabel = myLabel {

 }
```